# NVD3 RotateLabels not working on MultiChart

Tags: nvd3.js

First and last labels are rendered incorrectly. Does anyone know if there's a way to fix this, or is it a bug?

Here's how it's rendering for me

http://i.imgur.com/F4I9FjL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can change depending of the elements you've inside body tag. I've selected all `.nv-x` `.nv-axis` elements inside `<body>`. The line that defines the `attr` option, you can change de **translate** and **rotate** values.

```
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart();   
nv.addGraph(function() {

    ... (chart options like chart.x and chart.y, load data, etc.)

    d3.select('body')
        .selectAll('.nv-x.nv-axis > g')
        .selectAll('g')
        .selectAll('text')
        .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate (-13, 15) rotate(-45 0,0)' });
    });

    return chart;
});
```